# Как узнать адрес расположения переменной в памяти?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите, при помощи какой функции можно узнать адрес расположения переменной в памяти, чтобы получить возможность вывести адрес переменной на экран?

Comment: При помощи встроенной функции ```id()```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[id](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) вернет целое число, уникальное и постоянное для этого объекта в течение его жизни.
Два объекта с неперекрывающимися временами жизни могут иметь одинаковое значение id().
CPython: это адрес объекта в памяти.

[ctypes.cast(obj, type)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast) возвращает новый экземпляр типа, который указывает на тот же блок памяти, что и obj.
type должен быть указателем, а obj должен быть объектом, который можно интерпретировать как указатель.

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
I = id(A)

import ctypes
a = ctypes.cast(obj=I, typ=ctypes.py_object)
print(a.value)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
print(id(your_var))
```

Вы про это?

Comment: вообще, я имел ввиду, что-то вроде этого: <__main__.Manager object at 0x00000000028EC3C8>>, если конечно в таком виде, возможно получить адрес для переменной

Comment: @user364464 *Return the identity of an object.  This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.  __(Hint: it's the object's memory address.)__* специально выделил для вас. Можете перегрузить метод `__str__()` в тех, которые хотите так выводить по умолчанию.